# I have an error " subscript out of bound " while using h2o.confusionMatrix function in R

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o, confusion-matrix

Please find attached Error while building model and checking accuracy. I am using H2o package.
I have create model as h2o model. I want to apply the model in test and validation data .

My R code is:-

```
library(mlbench)
library(h2o)
h2o.init(nthreads = -1)
data("BreastCancer")

#Adjusting data types
data<-BreastCancer[,-1] #remove the ID column
#converting all columns to numeric type
data[,c(1:ncol(data))]<-sapply(data[,c(1:ncol(data))],as.numeric)
#convert class column to factor type
data[,'Class']<-as.factor(data[,'Class'])

#converting in the h2o format
splitsample<-sample(1:3,size=nrow(data),prob=c(0.6,0.2,0.2),replace=TRUE)
train_h2o<-as.h2o(data[splitsample==1,])
val_h2o<- as.h2o(data[splitsample==2,])
test_h2o<-as.h2o(data[splitsample==3,])
model<- h2o.deeplearning(x=1:9,# column number for predictors
                         y=10, #column number for label
                         #data in H2o format
                         training_frame = train_h2o,
                         #or 'Tanh'
                         # TanhWithDropout means Tanh function with regularization 
                         activation = "TanhWithDropout",
                         #% of inputs dropout
                         # It is used to drop bad or curropted or noise data
                         input_dropout_ratio = 0.2,
                         #balanced the two class 
                         balance_classes = TRUE,
                         #two hidden layers of 10 units
                         hidden = c(10,10),
                         #% for nodes dropout
                         # dropout probability for hidden layers
                         hidden_dropout_ratios = c(0.3,0.3),
                         #max no. of epochs
                         # Times of iterate data
                         epochs = 10,
                         seed=0)
h2o.confusionMatrix(model)


#validation confusion matrix

h2o.confusionMatrix(model,newdata=val_h2o)
```

My error is :

> Error in res$model_metrics[[1L]] : subscript out of bounds

Please anyone help me in deep learning. I am very grateful of you.

I have error in this code :-

h2o.confusionMatrix(model,newdata=val_h2o)

[Error in res$model_metrics[[1L]] : subscript out of bounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhZ28.png)

Comment: Please post a fully reproducible example (include data, or use a built-in dataset like iris, and all your code).

Comment: @ErinLeDell I update my post, please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the error, so I assume you are using some older version of H2O.  On the stable release of H2O (which today that is 3.10.5.2), I can execute your code with no errors.

```
> h2o.confusionMatrix(model,newdata=val_h2o)
Confusion Matrix (vertical: actual; across: predicted)  for max f1 @ threshold = 0.228804884732884:
        1  2    Error    Rate
1      89  2 0.021978   =2/91
2       0 46 0.000000   =0/46
Totals 89 48 0.014599  =2/137
```

If you encounter errors in the future, please make sure to try upgrading to the latest stable release of H2O and try again to see if that fixes the bug before reporting the error.  The link to the stable release is always on this [page](https://www.h2o.ai/download) and also on CRAN.  We release often, so it's good to make sure you are always running the latest version.